# BOOT Error: end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel

Tags: boot, sd-card, ubuntu

I did `sudo halt` and then power off the raspberry pi, then power off. And the next time I power on the pi, I can't boot the system anymore, and got this error.

[image]

I successfully run the commands `fsck -y /dev/sdb1` and `fsck -y /dev/sdb2` but it doesn't solve this problem.

I'm using raspberry pi 4B, on PI OS(32-BIT) released on 2022-09-22.

Comment: what else did you do prior to `sudo halt`

Comment: DO NOT post illegible pictures of text - post text. Your SD Card is probably corrupt. Restore from your backup.

Comment: @JaromandaX Nothing, everything is normal before `halt`, and did nothing after `halt`.

Comment: @Milliways Is there any method to restore it without losing data? I have no backups.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140600/8697 which is a similar question. The alternative is to do a fresh install to a new SD Card and recover your data .

Comment: You could try to read the SD card in a Linux system, copy all your important data, install a fresh system and restore the data.